# How to use Intel(R) UHD Graphics 730 for Blender?

Tags: gpu, memory-management

Here is the issue:

I am trying to use my Intel(R) UHD Graphics 730 GPU for Blender, but I can't add it as my GPU when I try to add it in preferences.

Just to prove I have a GPU and that Blender is currently using it, here is my Task Manager:

[image]

The minimum requirements for Blender say I need 2 GB memory on my GPU, and I have 5.8 GB of GPU memory. It should work, right?

Answer (score 1):

Blender needs **CUDA**, **OptiX**, **HIP** or **oneAPI** for rendering Cycles.

**Enable CUDA or OpenCL**:

- Depending on your GPU, you might need to enable either CUDA or OpenCL.
- For NVIDIA GPUs, choose "**CUDA**" or "**OptiX**" as the Compute Device.
- For AMD GPUs, choose "**HIP**" as the Compute Device
- For Intel Xe GPUs, choose "**oneAPI**" as the Compute Device

**Configure Blender**:

- Open Blender and go to "**Edit**" > "**Preferences**."
- In the Preferences window, select the "**System**" tab.
- Under the "**Cycles Render Devices**" section, choose your GPU as the Compute Device.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Make sure you have compatible GPU in your PC and updated drivers are installed